# Prevent image resizing in Pages

Tags: graphics, pages, iwork

If I paste in an image into Pages '09, it scales the image, creating something that is either too small, or too large. Trying to resize these is driving me crazy, how can I either prevent this from happening, or quickly get it back to its original size?

Comment: Have you tried grabbing a corner of the image and resizing? It's quite easy to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the "Inspector" on the "metrics" tab click "Original Size".

[image]

And for inserting images I prefer from the menu "Insert" and then "Choose..." or <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but the 'Original size' button just restores it to the 2x-size I get when I drag and drop the image. Any ideas?