# Pages: pasted images are too large

Tags: graphics, pages

Whenever I drag and drop an image into Pages from (for example) my browser, the image is resized to roughly 2x the original size. This causes annoying aliassing to occur; especially when taking screenshots and copy-pasting these it causes it to look blurred.

I saw the 'Original size'-button (as suggested [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43437/prevent-image-resizing-in-pages)) but when I click it, it just takes the image back to the 2x-size it had when pasting.

Is this something I can configure somewhere? Or should I not drag-and-drop images, but go through the hassle of importing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be due to the difference in resolution.

You will likely need to adjust the size/resolution of your images (can use preview for this).

Refer to the following discussions:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4472984
https://discussions.apple.com/message/11208784#11208784

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.